# Corrupted hard drive - how much data is recoverable?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, data-recovery

The laptop that I have no longer boots to Windows in any mode and so I took it in to a computer repair store. I was told that my hard drive is corrupted and that they would only be able to recover around 60% of the data.

Many of the files are very important and so I'm wondering is this percentage normal? Is it possible to recover more/all data from the drive?

The reason that the hard disk got damaged is because it was shut down during windows updates. How badly could this have affected the hard drive?

Thanks,

**Edit**: *All data was recoverable, only the windows sys files were affected in the corruption.*

Comment: first, establish the physical state of the disk by booting into a live CD and checking the SMART stats on the disk to make sure its healthy. Second, if it is mechanically healthy, use a tool like dd_rescue to create an image of the drive, and store it to another hard disk. Once thats done you can begin to attempt to recover the data using tools like Testdisk, photorec, etc. The response from your computer repair shop is kinda odd though. nothing about that sounds right. I assume standard maintenance routines like chkdsk haven't helped?

Comment: Unfortunately the disk drive hasn't been working for a while so this wouldn't be possible

Comment: Try something like R-Studio NTFS. You'll need to put the HDD into a caddy and attach it to another PC running Windows but it may be able to extract the useful information. It's $50 but cheaper than going to a dedicated company. This is not the only solution as there are other alternative possible products out there at varying price points.

Comment: ok, if the disk is mechanically healthy, as would be implied by your description (improper shutdown with pending write operations on the filesystem), then it doesn't matter how long the drive has been out of service. if you have any chance of recovering data, the drive must at least power up. so is it mechanically dead (indicating that you have 0% hope of recovering data) or not?

Comment: No, it powers up, it just can't boot into windows. A thought just struck me that it could be that step that is corrupted, and that once you get past the corrupted windows files the data should be ok. All I can do is hope now, I've left it in to see what the repair store can do. Thanks for trying to help though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note: This is a somewhat vague question. So I can only give you a vague answer.*

Shut downs while the hard drive is running can do a lot of damage. Typically, it's limited to the files the drive is working with at the time. What caused the shut down can be a factor too. Every situation is different.

In my experience, as long as the data was not corrupt before the shut down during Windows Update, then you should be able to recover it. If no other programs were running or files open when the shut down occurred, the corruption they are reporting is probably related to Windows files. Therefore, it is likely your personal data files will be recovered, but Windows and programs will need to be reinstalled.

The percentage they are telling you is an estimate and may contain your personal data, while the 40% is likely Windows files. There is no way we can give you a definitive answer here.

Answer (score 0):

There is no rule of thumb about how much data can be recovered from a broken disk, it all depends what kind of failure it sustained.
Degraded components simply requiring low level utilities to run to save the data on another unit?
Broken reading device or logic circuitry with no surface damage? 
Physical surface damages due to use or an hit?
How extended are the damages?
... so the question if 60% is normal cannot really be answered.
If they come up with a percentage after running a diagnostic tool, the guess might be quite accurate.